# React native fails to start watch mode or gets stuck while Building JavaScript bundle

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have been working with React native for a few days now. Everything seemed to be working fine until I installed Nativebase. Now either I would get this error:

[image: Failed to start watch mode]

OR it would get stuck at around 97% while Building JavaScript bundle after a couple of Project restarts and clearing cache. This happens regardless of whether I'm running on my phone or the emulator. I'm using the Expo XDE but its the same with the cmd.

Comment: This error usually happens if you don't have watchman installed on your machine. Have you installed it?